# suction surface pressures

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "suction surface pressures" in the following sentence correct grammatically? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

On the other hand, with increased blade loading on the blade surface (use of thicker airfoils), **suction surface pressures** are reduced, and the velocity and Mach number over the suction surface increase with the local Mach number reaching supersonic values.

Is it better to use of "pressure of suction surface" or "pressures on the suction surface"?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Books claims almost 4000 written instances of ["suction surface pressure"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22suction+surface+pressure%22), so I suggest you just stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would think "pressure on the suction surface is reduced" because this appears to be discussing lift, and "on the...surface" helps to clarify this.